# exchange+activesync: Allow to sync only calendar, but not email

Tags: exchange-2010, activesync

I'm using SBS2011 with Exchange 2010 in it. I figured out how to set up activesync. But what I need is basically sync only calendar, not emails to iPhone/Android devices. Emails are managed by booking people and installer workers need to sync only calendar events. Is this possible?

Comment: Go to the app "sync" settings and you can tell it what you want to sync...